# Consolidate table from vertical to horizontal efficiently

Tags: r, transpose, consolidation

I have a large table with unique characteristics that occur on multiple IDs (**table A**).
Is there a clever workaround in which I could horizontally consolidate the values so that in the second **table B** I have unique IDs in the rows and in the columns occurring characteristics (which also occur in different numbers per ID)? The fields for missing features in an ID row I want to fill with NA. Since I have a maximum of 22 unique characteristics per ID, the maximum number of columns should be 23 (with ID).

With the loop it works, but it takes forever.

**I tried all solutions from [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584) without success.**

E.g., for `reshape`, `cast`, `dcast`, and other functions the vector
is too large giving:
`Error: cannot allocate vector of size ...`

[image: Vertical Table]
[image: Horizontal Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new column in Table A then you can use `pivot_wider` quite easily:

```r
library(tidyverse)

table_a <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
  feature = c("df", "ftv", "ed", "wed", "rfc", "dtb", "bes", "xrd", "yws")
)

table_b <- table_a %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(feature_name = paste0("feature", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = feature_name, values_from = feature)
  
table_b
# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Groups:   id [3]
     id feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 df       ftv      NA       NA      
2     2 ed       wed      rfc      dtb     
3     3 bes      xrd      yws      NA
```

Comment: This is it. With tidyverse it works. Many thanks for your suggestion.